# Where was the Quaritch recombinant "born"?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

In *Avatar: The Way of Water*, we see the Quaritch recombinant waking up in a lab somewhere for the first time. Shortly afterwards, he is in a transport craft and says "we're on our way to Pandora", implying that they weren't on Pandora before. The vehicle they are in looks like the ones which transport people from the ISVs to the Pandora surface.

Is there any indication of where this lab was located where the Quaritch recombinant was "born"? Possible options I can think of are:

1. The lab was on Earth, and the lab scene was a flashback, as it takes 5-6 years to travel from Earth to Pandora. This would be a bit strange as Quaritch's comments to his squad indicate they have all only just woken up ("*I know you are all asking yourselves the same question: is it Blue Monday? The sins of the past have made us reborn in the form of our enemies*")
2. The lab was on Earth, and there was an unseen timeskip of 5-6 years (which would be even more strange as these scenes occur right after a "one year later" timeskip)
3. The lab was actually inside the ISV itself (which I believe would be the first time we saw such facility inside an ISV, previous shots seemed to indicate it was just a massive cryo chamber)
4. The lab was on some other planet close to Pandora
5. The lab was on Pandora, and Quaritch's comment that "we're on our way to Pandora" was an error

Comment: Are you forgetting that there's at least 12 years between the events of the first film (when the humans are kicked off of Pandora) and the re-arrival of the humans?  Certainly enough time for a human baby (Spider) to have grown to mid-teenage, as well as Sully's hybrid children, and Grace's avatar's mystery child.  It doesn't seem like there's missing time to me.  The labs on Pandora would have been under the control of the Pandorans and human sympathizers, so it's either Earth, or in transit.  Regardless, I'm guessing they were created and left in suspended state until they neared Pandora.

Comment: iirc it looked like the lab had got gravity which makes it being on an ISV very unlikely. It's certainly not on Pandora as you hear PA announcements about landing.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm Not sure what you mean, yes I'm aware that there's a large time gap between the two films. I'm only talking about the scene where Quaritch "wakes up" in the lab and where that scene is set. I infer from your answer that you think this happened shortly before arriving at Pandora i.e. on the ISV, which as another commenter pointed out is unlikely as the lab has gravity.